# Resizable divs side by side

Tags: resize, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery/JQueryUI hortizontal divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139096/jquery-jqueryui-hortizontal-divider)

How do I put two divs side by side and make them both resize together. I want the effect of a movable divider between two divs like windows explorer.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to demonstrate how you have these divs laid out on the page. How is the user expected to resize the divs? Is it through javascript, changing the font size in her browser, entering a value in a form, or what?

Comment: Something like [this](http://jquery.jcubic.pl/splitter.php)?

Comment: (I know the page title and contents of the _possible duplicate_ is for horizontal and you want vertical, but the answer appears identical in any case.)

Comment: Thanks Danny.  The jquery splitter is what I was looking for. @BlueRaja

Answer (score 0):

One of the divs must be the container for the other. Float the inner div and set a margin on the outer div to match the width of the inner.  That will allow the content for each div to show where it needs to horizontally. Then set the height of the inner to 100%, so that it always fills up the vertical space on the outer div and can stretch it if needed.